# Building gstreamer using Yocto

Tags: yocto

I am trying to build gstreamer for IMX53 Evk board.
I downloaded Yocto from  http://freescale.github.io/#download and run the following commands.

```
#MACHINE=imx53qsb
#source setup-environment build
#bitbake core-image-minimal
```

It built the u-boot, kernel and filesystem. The file system doesn't have gstreamer. I want to built gstreamer also.

As per my understanding there two approaches to built gstreamer now.

> Approach 1. Modify the distro.conf file to build gstreamer also. I
>   am not sure how to add gstreamer entries in the distro.conf. The
>   distribution is poky distribution.
>
> Approach 2. Add IMAGE_INSTALL_append with gstreamer entries. My
>   doubht here is what names we have to add in the IMAGE_INSTALL_append.

I could see the following bb files related to gstreamer. Can you please help what strings I have to add in IMAGE_INSTALL_append in local.conf.

```
./meta-fsl-arm/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-fsl-plugin_4.0.3.bb
./meta-fsl-arm/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst1.0-fsl-plugin_4.0.3.bb
./meta-fsl-arm/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-imx_0.11.1.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good_0.10.31.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-meta-base_0.10.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0_git.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-fluendo-mp3_0.10.31.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly_1.4.5.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-meta-base.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0_1.4.5.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-omx_git.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer_0.10.36.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-openmax_0.10.1.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-libav_git.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-plugins-ugly_0.10.19.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-ffmpeg_0.10.13.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-player_git.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base_0.10.36.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-plugins-gl_0.10.3.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-libav_1.4.5.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_git.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.4.5.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.4.5.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad_0.10.23.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_1.4.5.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_git.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-omx_1.2.0.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly_git.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server_1.4.5.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_git.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-fluendo-mpegdemux_0.10.85.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/bluez/gst-plugin-bluetooth_4.101.bb
./meta-fsl-demos/recipes-fsl/packagegroups/packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer.bb
./meta-fsl-demos/recipes-fsl/packagegroups/packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer-full.bb
./meta-fsl-demos/recipes-multimedia/packagegroups/packagegroup-fslc-gstreamer1.0-full.bb
./meta-fsl-demos/recipes-multimedia/packagegroups/packagegroup-fslc-gstreamer1.0-commercial.bb
./meta-fsl-demos/recipes-multimedia/packagegroups/packagegroup-fslc-gstreamer1.0.bb
./meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-rtsp_0.10.8.bb
./meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia/recipes-multimedia/nonworking/gstreamer/gst123_0.3.1.bb
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may add just

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "gstreamer"
```

Long answer is that you should add the package name that usually stored in PN recipe variable. You may read about PN variable [here](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PN). Package names may also be managed with PACKAGES [variable](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PACKAGES).

Comment: @ aleksandrm8 :  Thanks for the info. I am bit confused about PN usage for package. My understanding is bitbake will take each recipe and perform fetch,unpack,configure,build,package tasks.In the PN variable definition it was updated that "PN will take the package name in the context of a file created or produced". I didn't understand this clearly. Can you please help to understand PN usage while building package.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand clearly what exactly you didn't understand clearly in phrase "PN will take the package name in the context of a file created or produced". I think you can understand it like "PN is extracted from the recipe file name, so PN is both recipe name (expat_2.0.1.bb) and package name (expat).".

Comment: My understanding: for creating a package we should have a .bb file and involved "fetch,unpack,configure,compile,create package" tasks while processing .bb. When bitbake starts building .bb file, it will store the recipe(.bb file) name in PN variable. So that the package name is same as recipe name.
After reading about PN variable in Yocto reference link, I got a doubt that whether PN variable will have a string(recipe name)  in the context of a file used by OE build and will have a different string(may be different from recipe name) in the context of a file created or produced by OE build.

Comment: The name of the package is "gstreamer1.0" and not "gstreamer", at least on recent yocto versions.

Comment: "gstreamer1.0" works like a charm, but what I don't understand is what is the source of this application? I mean we didn't add .bb file that fetches sources from somewhere. However, we got the application, so is this hidden in meta-openembedded layer or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You either use 
`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gstreamer"`
or
`IMAGE_INSTALL += " gstreamer"`

They do the same things but `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` is best when using with this variable.

The space in front of gstreamer is important because.
let's say IMAGE_INSTALL is a string: `"opkg qtbase"`
and if we do not add a space in front. 
IMAGE_INSTALL will be like this: `"opkg qtbasegstreamer"` which will cause error.

Answer (score 0):

Advice is correct on getting package name. First find recipe. bitbake-layers is useful for this. Then check that PN and PACKAGES variables are not set, if they are things get tricky. For gstreamer they are not

If you're new to Yocto, I'd go with adding package in local.conf. Entry in should be be IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " gstreamer". The space before gstreamer is important.